# How do I stop event propagation with rightclick on Leaflet marker?

Tags: leaflet, events, markers

I didn't find a rightclick event in Leaflet markers so I started listening to the mousedown event. In the method that resolves this event I check

```
if (event.originalEvent.button == 2) {
    do_something();
    // now i want to stop propagation of the rightclick
    return;
}
```

This does work in that do_something() is called, but the event propagates to the map and a contextmenu is being shown. How do I prevent the event to propagate to the map?

Does this work in all major (i.e. IE) browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first answer was apparently not working and as I am now facing the same problem. Here is a new approach:

Leaflet supports an event called `contextmenu`. As found in the Leaflet event documentation [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events).

> Fired when the user pushes the right mouse button on the map, *prevents default browser context menu from showing* if there are listeners on this event.

So theoretically the code

```
marker.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
  this.openPopup();
});
```

*should* work just fine. **But** apparently the implementation lags behind the documentation. As of now (Leaflet 0.4.5) the `contextmenu` event is apparently *not* yet supported on markers, although it works perfectly fine on polyline objects.

There seems to be work in the pipeline to enable this feature in the near future (see discussions [here](https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/pull/427) and [here](https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/issues/998)). So, I guess we can just hope that Leaflet works on this quickly and enables the event in the next release...

**Edit:**
Disregard what I said about waiting for the implementation. If you download the latest development master branch and build leaflet yourself you get full support for `contextmenu` events on markers. Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

Try this internal function:

```
L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
```

It should do the trick.

P.S. I never found that in any documentation but saw it used in a patch. Use at your own risk. ;)

*Edit:* I also found this internal function

```
L.DomEvent.preventDefault(event);
```

Which seems to be very much the same as `event.preventDefault()` which is in jQuery.

Comment: I used your snippet, but what happens is the same as with tmcw's solution. I rightclick my marker. It goes to the listening method. There it removes the marker (that is what rightclick should do for me) and then a context menu opens on the map where i clicked as if the whole marker thing didnt happen.

Comment: By chance I just found this `L.DomEvent.preventDefault(event);`. From what I've seen (looking at the Leaflet.js source) this should be very similar to the `preventDefault()` provided by jQuery... Try it out! :)

Comment: I tried it, but the standard contextmenu i get in FF when i rightclick on an html page keeps popping up.

Answer (score 4):

Preventing default behavior in IE and all other browsers:

```
event.returnValue = false;
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Have you tested this in Leaflet? And is your event a leaflet event or the original DOMMouseEvent fired by the browser?

Comment: This is for a DOM event. If Leaflet wraps events, use event.originalEvent.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution incidentally for stopping event.

For example, if an event is created like this - `map.on("click", onMapClick);`, the event can be stopped with this code - `map.off("click", onMapClick);`