# Stop Leaflet event propagation?

Tags: leaflet

I have a feature layer and some pins on it, with mouseout, mouseover events callbacks on the feature. When the mouse is over the pin icon, that triggers mouseout event (mouseout from the feature layer). I am trying to stop event propagation but nothing works.

How can the leaflet event propagation be stopped?

None of those worked:

```
DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
DomEvent.preventDefault(e);
DomEvent.stop(e);
stopPropagation(e.originalEvent);
preventDefault(e.originalEvent);
stop(e.originalEvent);
```

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question, otherwise any help attempt would be just guessing.

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42179/49538

Answer (score 3):

Okay, finally got it figured out on stopping the propagation of events.
e.g.

```
someReference.on("click", (evt: L.LeafletEvent) => {
    // You don't try to reference the event (evt) that is passed in

    L.DomEvent.preventDefault(evt); // Just call this
    ...
})
```

Comment: This prevents the DOM event from propagating outside of leaflet, but doesn't seem to prevent leaflet itself from propagating the click through its own layers, which requires the `bubblingMouseEvents` on your marker to be set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in stopping propagation for a Marker, you can just set `bubblingMouseEvents` to `false` in the options: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-bubblingmouseevents

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions offered here and at other questions, and only this worked for me:

```
L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(ev);
```